# Getting the pitch of a rotation in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, point-cloud-library, plane

I have received that function in my code, written by someone else. I don't understand the theory behind it, but it seems to be working.
Does somebody could lead me in the right direction ?

We are calculating the slope of a road from a pointcloud with ransac. 
rotation is the world to local matrix, so plane_normal_rot is the normal vector of the plane in the world.
But after that I don't understand what is going on..

```
ransac.getModelCoefficients(model_coefficients);                                                                                                     

std::cout << "#############################" << std::endl;                                                                                           
std::cout << "PLANE MODEL: " << model_coefficients[0]  << " "<< model_coefficients[1] << " "<< model_coefficients[2] << " " << model_coefficients[3];
std::cout << "#############################" << std::endl;                                                                                           

double a = model_coefficients[0];                                                                                                                    
double b = model_coefficients[1];                                                                                                                    
double c = model_coefficients[2];                                                                                                                    

tf::Vector3 plane_normal(a,b,c);                                                                                                                     
tf::Vector3 plane_normal_rot(0,0,0);                                                                                                                 

//tf::Matrix3x3 rotation_tr = rotation.transpose();                                                                                                  
tf::Matrix3x3 rotation_tr = rotation;                                                                                                                

plane_normal_rot.setX( (plane_normal.getX() *  rotation_tr[0][0])                                                                                    
        + (plane_normal.getY() *  rotation_tr[0][1])                                                                                                 
        + (plane_normal.getZ() *  rotation_tr[0][2]));                                                                                               

plane_normal_rot.setY( (plane_normal.getX() *  rotation_tr[1][0])                                                                                    
        + (plane_normal.getY() *  rotation_tr[1][1])                                                                                                 
        + (plane_normal.getZ() *  rotation_tr[1][2]));                                                                                               

plane_normal_rot.setZ( (plane_normal.getX() *  rotation_tr[2][0])                                                                                    
        + (plane_normal.getY() *  rotation_tr[2][1])                                                                                                 
        + (plane_normal.getZ() *  rotation_tr[2][2]));                                                                                               

//Check sign                                                                                                                                         
if(plane_normal_rot.getZ() < 0)                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                                    
    plane_normal_rot *= (-1);                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                    

pitch = asin(plane_normal_rot.getX());
```

If I havn't been clear or you feel like you're missing info please tell me.

Comment: What precisely is your problem? I cannot see how you compute the slope. The slope should be the angle between the vertical (z-axis) and the plane-normal, i.e. acos(z-component of normalized plane normal). The angle called pitch here, gives the orientation of the direction of steepest slope w.r.t. the y-direction.

Comment: @Walter I would like to get the pitch and the roll, this my final goal. But I don't understand what is the calculation doing after the matrix multiplication.  Also I agree with you when you say "The slope should be the angle between the vertical (z-axis) and the plane-normal" but how do you arrive to acos(z-component of normalized plane normal) ?